# How to unpack and print a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python (3.x), this is my first post here, and I am trying to unpack a tuple, then print it with a certain format (my words may not be quite right).  Here is what I have:

```
w = 45667.778
x = 56785.55
y = 34529.4568
z = 789612.554

nums = (w, x, y, z)
hdr62 = '{:>15} {:>15} {:>15} {:>15}'

print(tuple('${:,.0f}'.format(num).rjust(12, ' ') for num in nums))
```

What/how do I alter to unpack and then use the hdr62 format to print the tuple?

Comment: Could you add a link to a description of the hdr62 format?

Comment: hdr62 is just a spacing format -- it is defined just below "nums" above.

Comment: Heh... here I am googling hdr62, thinking it's some standard I've never heard of. It's too early...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I’m missing things, but if you just want to format the tuple `nums` according to the `hdr62` format, then you can just call `str.format` on it and pass in the numbers as unpacked tuple:

```
>>> print(hdr62.format(*nums))
      45667.778        56785.55      34529.4568      789612.554
```

If you actually want to run another format on the tuple items first, you can do that separately:

```
>>> ['${:,.0f}'.format(n) for n in nums]
['$45,668', '$56,786', '$34,529', '$789,613']
>>> print(hdr62.format(*['${:,.0f}'.format(n) for n in nums]))
        $45,668         $56,786         $34,529        $789,613
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and the comments below, you can first use the tuple comprehension to format your numbers and then call the formatting. The `format` call can be done with an asterisk (`*`), so:

```
nums2 = tuple('${:,.0f}'.format(num).rjust(12, ' ') for num in nums)
print(hdr62.format(*nums2))
```

If you call a function and use an asterisk, the parameter (which should be a sequence) behind the curtains Python unpacks the sequence and feed it as separate parameters, so in this case:

```
nums2 = tuple('${:,.0f}'.format(num).rjust(12, ' ') for num in nums)
print(hdr62.format(*nums2))
```

is equivalent to:

```
nums2 = tuple('${:,.0f}'.format(num).rjust(12, ' ') for num in nums)
print(hdr62.format(nums[0],nums[1],nums[2],nums[3]))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am too much of a beginner to understand your answer.  I am trying to print the 4 variables using the print statement above, and using the spacing hdr62 -- can you be more specific on what to add and where?

Comment: where would I add '${:,.0f}' to get the correct format of the number that is printed?

Comment: @Dennis: ah you want to format the *result* of your last statement,not of `nums` itself?

Comment: yes, I want the result to be $45,668 ..... with proper spacing between the numbers, right justified in a field length of 12

Comment: @Dennis: but your `hdr62` says the justification should be 15?

Comment: Thank you - your solution works fine. I appreciate your help